# How to unpack the columns of a pandas DataFrame to multiple variables

Tags: python, pandas, syntactic-sugar

Lists or numpy arrays can be unpacked to multiple variables if the dimensions match. For a 3xN array, the following will work:

```
import numpy as np 
a,b =          [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
a,b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
# result: a=[1,2,3],   b=[4,5,6]
```

How can I achieve a similar behaviour for the columns of a pandas `DataFrame`? Extending the above example:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
df.columns = ['A','B','C']    # Rename cols and
df.index = ['i', 'ii']        # rows for clarity
```

The following does not work as expected:

```
a,b = df.T
# result: a='i',   b='ii'
a,b,c = df
# result: a='A',   b='B',   c='C'
```

However, what I would like to get is the following:

```
a,b,c = unpack(df)
result: a=df['A'], b=df['B'], c=df['C']
```

Is the function `unpack` already available in pandas? Or can it be mimicked in an easy way?

Comment: Not sure why since you could just use if you don't like the `[]` and it isn't a name that conflicts with df methods so the dot attribute method will work `df.a` (etc) to access them, but are you after: `a, b, c = df['A'], df['B'], df['C']` ?

Comment: Not actually, because I don't want to bother about column names. With unpacking I refer to the same thing as described in [PEP3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Comment: Sure, but I don't get *why* you want to unpack them instead of just directly accessing the name on the dataframe object itself... what does `a = df.a` get you over just using `df.a` except another reference that might keep columns in your DF alive unnecessarily?

Comment: Readability, for example, if the column names are complicated.

Comment: In your numpy example, you're using it to provide convenient names - in a DataFrame - you already have them... If as you mention column names are complicated, then just use `df.rename(columns={'some stupidly long name that's a pain in the rear to keep typing out': 'short_name'}, inplace=True)` if you find you keep having to assign a reasonable name to it, or just unpack the tricky ones such as: `a, b = df['laskdjflaskdjflasdkfjladfsjladsjflaskdjflasdfj'], df['asdfjlasdoijasdofjnasdfkjlaskdf']`and access the rest on the df itself.

Comment: I agree that this is an option. To use `loc` or `iloc` is also one. But my question is whether the behaviour of lists and np.arrays was translated to pandas Dataframes, and not how to circumvent the missing feature in case it was not.

Comment: It's not a behaviour of lists / arrays in particular - unpacking will apply to whatever the source object provides as an `__iter__` - in this case a `DataFrame` chooses to expose its columns names... a `np.array` will returns its rows (for a 2d array)... a `dict` will return its keys etc...

Comment: If you really want you can just access `df.values` which'll give you the underlying numpy array...

Comment: Jupp, your right. Your comment just crossed my answer. If you type your own answer, I'd accept yours and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Nah it's fine... :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just figured that the following works, which is already close to what I try to achieve:

```
a,b,c = df.T.values        # Common
a,b,c = df.T.to_numpy()    # Recommended
# a,b,c = df.T.as_matrix() # Deprecated
```

---

**Details:** As always, things are a little more complicated than one thinks. Note that a `pd.DataFrame` [stores](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html) columns separately in Series. Calling [`df.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) (or better: [`df.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html)) is potentially *expensive*, as it combines the columns in a single [`ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), which likely involves copying actions and type conversions. Also, the resulting container has a single `dtype` able to accommodate all data in the data frame.

In summary, the above approach loses the per-column dtype information and is potentially expensive. It is technically cleaner to iterate the columns in one of the following ways (there are more options):

```py
# The following alternatives create VIEWS!
a,b,c = (v for _,v in df.items())      # returns pd.Series
a,b,c = (df[c] for c in df)            # returns pd.Series
```

Note that the above creates [views](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)! Modifying the data likely will trigger a `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

```py
a.iloc[0] = "blabla"    # raises SettingWithCopyWarning
```

If you want to modify the unpacked variables, you have to copy the columns.

```py
# The following alternatives create COPIES!
a,b,c = (v.copy() for _,v in df.items())      # returns pd.Series
a,b,c = (df[c].copy() for c in df)            # returns pd.Series
a,b,c = (df[c].to_numpy() for c in df)        # returns np.ndarray
```

While this is cleaner, it requires more characters. I personally do not recommend the above approach for production code. But to avoid typing (e.g., in interactive shell sessions), it is still a fair option...

```py
# More verbose and explicit alternatives
a,b,c = df["the first col"], df["the second col"], df["the third col"]
a,b,c = df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1], df.iloc[:,2]
```

Comment: from version 0.24.0 you can also do
`a, b, c = df.T.to_numpy() `

Comment: Be careful with that. Transposing may change the type of your data as type is specific to column. If you have say some integers those might get converted to objects or floats and in the later case you'll loose the precision.

Comment: @Emsi Thanks for the comment. I've updated my answer with a couple of details. Note that the information about column types is not lost just because of the transposition, but because of [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `dataframe.values` shown method is indeed a good solution, but it involves building a numpy array.

In the case you want to access pandas series methods after unpacking, I personally use a different approach.

For the people like me that use a lot of chained methods, I have a solution by adding a custom unpacking method to pandas. Note that this may not be very good for production pipelines, but it is very handy in ad-hoc data analyses.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "lat": [30, 40], 
    "lon": [0, 1],
})
```

This approach involves returning a generator on a `.unpack()` call.

```
from typing import Tuple

def unpack(self: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[pd.Series]:
    return (
        self[col]
        for col in self.columns
    )

pd.DataFrame.unpack = unpack
```

This can be used in two major ways.

Either directly as a solution to your problem:

```
lat, lon = df.unpack()
```

Or, can be used in a method chaining.
Imagine a geo function which has to take a latitude serie in the first arg and a longitude in the second arg, named `do_something_geographical(lat, lon)`

```
df_result = (
    df
        .(...some method chaining...)
        .assign(
            geographic_result=lambda dataframe: do_something_geographical(dataframe[["lat", "lon"]].unpack())
        )
        .(...some method chaining...)
)
```